# How to send a label's text as an email attachment?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, sdk, email-attachments

I want to attach a label text to an email,
How can I send a text inside a UILabel as an attachment to email ?

This is the code I'm using :

```
-(IBAction)send:(id)sender {

    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 100, 300, 100)];
        label.numberOfLines = 0;
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentCenter;
        label.text = @"text";

        [self.view addSubview:label];
        [label release];

        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailer setSubject:@"Subject"];

        NSString *fileName = @"my file.txt";
        NSArray  *paths =   NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *path = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];

        NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
        [mailer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:fileName];

        // Fill out the email body text
        NSString *emailBody = @"Email Body";

        [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

        [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];

        [mailer release];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alertm = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                         message:@"Please make sure that your   email application is open"
                                                        delegate:nil
                                               cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                               otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertm show];
        [alertm release];
    }
}
```

How can I link that label to attach it to email ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What format do you want to send it as? A .txt file?

Comment: @woz he asked to send self.label.text not some file on disk

Comment: @woz My problem that with this code I can see the attachment.txt when the Mail view controller open but when the email received there is nothing inside it, I don't know why. Can you please help me ?

Answer (score 0):

you're almost there.

-- you read text from a file and attach it

===

read the data not from the file but from the label itself

```
NSData *data = [self.label.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8Encoding];
```

Comment: So that means that I need to replace :         NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path]; with your code. But I think if do that I will get an error for the ( path ) which is declared in my code, or am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

You can add the Label text to the Body.

```
        NSString *emailBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your Voice File Attached. %@", label.text];
```

something like this

Comment: I want to add it as an attachment so it will not be editable .

Comment: ah, sorry.
then i think you have to add the Label Text to your "file.txt" file.

Comment: or you attach a second .txt file with the label.text

Comment: Sorry I didn't get your suggestion, can you give me a code please ?